# BC42025 warning with "Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor"

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting this warning **BC42025** when I use `Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor`, what should I use instead? I don't want to ignore this warning.

**Warning BC4025**:
*"Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression Status
Warning BC42025 Shared member, constant member, enum member, or nested type access through an instance; the qualifying expression will not be evaluated."*

Comment: What warning? Why make us search for that code when you have the actual earning message right in front of you? ALWAYS provide ALL the relevant information.

Comment: I edited the post and added it... It was in Portuguese, I translated it, I hope it's ok now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

that has cursor as object

Of course you can also qualify your cursor directly with

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current
```

Comment: It solved my problem but I used a mass replace from `Cursor.Current` to `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current`

Comment: @HeitorBadotti, if you qualified the type in your code rather than using the `Imports` as suggested then the answer did not solve your problem. They are not the same thing. You should add your own answer and explain what you actually did. The issue is that your unqualified reference to the `Cursor` class was being interpreted as the `Cursor` property of the current object. I didn't think that VS actually did that any more. Are you using the latest version or an older version?

Comment: @jmcilhinney even VS 2022 needs to import or qualify the Cursor

Comment: @jmcilhinney But it solved the problem, the errors disappeared...